# Definition of locally integrable

Tags: measure-theory

If $m$ is a Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the wikipedia says

> (1) $f$ is locally integrable if $\int_K f dm < \infty$ for every compact set $K$.

But why is this condition equivalent to

> (2) $f$ is locally integrable if $\int_B f dm < \infty$ for every bounded measurable set $B$?
>   as defined in Folland's book Real Analysis?

The direction $(2) \rightarrow (1)$ is clear, but what about the other direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both definitions need a correction. $f$ is locally integrable if $\int_K |f| <\infty$ for every compact set $K$ and this is equivalent to the condition  $\int_K |f| <\infty$ for every bounded measurable set $K$. You cannot drop the absolute value sign in the definitions. The equivalence is obvious because any compact set is a bounded measurable set and any bounded measurable set is contained in a closed ball which is a compact set.

Comment: Why is it wrong to drop the absolute value?

Comment: $\int f <\infty$ does not say $f$ is intergable. Integrals can be $-\infty$ too, right?. If you want talk about integrability you should either say it on words or say $\int |f| <\infty$.